# select items in ListView<items> and return null in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

ShapeFX class that contains an ArrayList  shapes

```
    public class ShapeFX {

        private ArrayList<Shapes> shapes;

        public ShapeFX () {
            this.shapes= new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public ShapeFX (ArrayList<Shapes> shapes) {
            this.shapes= shapes;
        }

        public ArrayList<Shapes> getShapes() {
            return this.shapes;
        }

        public void setShapes(ArrayList<Shapes> shapes) {
            this.shapes= shapes;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return this.shapes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Shapes element) {
            this.shapes.add(element);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(Shapes element) {
            if (element != null) {
                this.shapes.remove(element);
            } 
        }

 @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        Iterator itr = this.formaGeometricas.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            str.append(itr.toString());
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    }
```

Here I have just a small example of two events in JavaFX with buttons **create shapes** and **remove shapes**, only the method **add(Shapes element)** it works, the method **remove(Shapes element)** does not work because after the shapes is created, when I try to remove the shapes, I receive the message **DOESN´T EXIST ANY SHAPES**

```
      //in JavaFX
      ShapesFX shapesFX = new ShapesFx();

      ObservableArrayList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Circle", "Triangle");
      ComboBox<String>comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);

      Button btnCreate = new Button("Create Shapes");     
      btnCreate.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

           //here is function very well
           Object items = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

           if (items.equals("Circle")) {
                Point2D p1 = new Point2D(0, 0);
                              //public class Circle extends Shapes
                 shapesFX.add(new Circle(p1, Color.BLACK, Float.valueOf(radiusTextField.getText())));
           } else if (items.equals("Triangle")) {
                 Point2D p2 = new Point2D(0, 0);
                               //public class Triangle extends Shapes
                  shapesFX.add(new Triangle(p2, Color.BLACK, Float.valueOf(sizeTextField.getText())));                 
                    }
                });
```

The error is begin in this part, when I try to select item in ListView (Shapes shape = **list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();)** or the error is in  ObservableList listShapes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(**shapesFX.getShapes()**);

```
//or the error is here when I made (shapesFX.getShapes())
final ObservableList<Shapes> listShapes = FXCollections.observableArrayList(shapesFX.getShapes());
        final ListView<Shapes> list = new ListView<>(listShapes);

        Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove Shapes");  
        btnRemove.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                // or the error is here
                Shapes shape = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if (shape != null) {
                        shapesFX.remove(shape);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("DOESN´T EXIST ANY SHAPES");
                }
            }
        })
```

after inserting the data and click on **btnCreate** to create a shape, in this part the shape is created successfully.

but when I click on **btnRemove** to delete the created shape, and when I do this **Shapes shape = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();** to browse and select the shape that will clean, and instead of the shape be return different from null like this **(forms != null)**, the shape will return null (and then displays the message **DOESN´T EXIST ANY SHAPES**) as if no shape was not created

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Plus: if possible please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It really makes easier, both for you, who need help and for us who are trying to help you.

Comment: Hi, its not a error, when I click the btnRemove to remove shapes, the application said, DOESN´T EXIST ANY SHAPES, because Shapes shape = list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), it´s return shape == null, not shape != null;

Comment: Presumably the `ListView` you create in the code you have shown is the same one you added to the UI...?